# What do cultist characters in the H. P. Lovecraft mythos particularly value?

Tags: h-p-lovecraft, money

I'm designing a role playing game set in a Lovecraft-inspired world, and I need some kind of currency in it. The obvious one that comes to my mind is just gold, but since in rpgs atmosphere plays a very important role, I'd rather find something more original — or at least have some background story as to why gold is considered valuable by cultists and such.

In other words, if you were a Shub-Niggurath worshipper, what would you pay with for a copy of Necronomicon?

Is there anything in the mythos (Lovecraft stories, or Lovecraft-inspired stories) that is of particular value to cultists? Maybe something abstract like *vitae*? I'm open to any ideas.

Comment: I assume you're referring to a setting inspired by Lovecraft's [Dreamlands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dream_Cycle), rather than the ones set in (then-)modern day USA, right? Since if it's the latter, than the US Dollar is probably used by cultists too.

Comment: Shubcoin? Just forking now, gimme a minute.

Comment: Yes, United States dollars are used in most of the places the stories take place. Gold also works. You realize those took place on planet Earth, do you not?

Comment: On-Topic: "Is there a currency used in the HP Lovecraft mythos?" Off-Topic: "Help me come up with a new currency."

Comment: To those saying this question is opinion-based: I'm not asking for answers like Shubcoin, I'm just asking if there's anything of particular value to cultists, aside from simple gold and dollars. Maybe orbs, stones or something abstract like the already mentioned vitae, or life essence. I'm asking because I've only read a dozen or so of Lovecraft's stories, and almost none Lovecraft-inspired ones. So maybe someone here has a better knowledge of Lovecraft mythos.

Comment: This question is economically ignorant. I value leather furniture, but no one would call that a currency. Given the time period and locations of HPL stories, we've given you the only sensible answers to your question. Even if you're talking about Leng and so forth, model that on Europe or China... we know how city-states and nations handle these things in general.

Comment: @JohnO Hm, I guess you're right. Sorry for taking your time, then.

Comment: @Dunno No need to apologize... even though I voted to close the question, I still wanted to provide a real answer to what you've asked. For the Dreamland stuff, just read up on how all the old city-states of Greece and whatnot minted their own coinage, make up some names for yours, and go with it. Gold and silver. In the future, try to ask without explaining why you want the answer, that "helps" when it comes to the off-topic closing.

Comment: The real difficulty in finding a sensible motivation for a Lovecraft cultist is that they are mad by definition. So they might really want a tome of arcane knowlege, but rather than save up shekels they would invoke a night terror to steal it.